# Fabric twitter, memory leak at init

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-fabric

I have detected memory leaks when initializing fabric

Screenshots from  leak instruments
[image]

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this leaks ?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here,  I'd recommend making sure you're on the last versions of all the Fabric kits.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I'm using the last versions. Fabric (1.6.11), Crashlytics (3.8.4) and Digits (2.8.0).

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce this unfortunately given the screenshot above. I tested the same code and had no leaks.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I added stack trace, hope it can help. Any ideahow can I resolve this leaks ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks more like a bug report directed at the Fabric devs.

Comment: Based on the stack trace, do you have app icons for all sizes?